# Will a 2015 MacBook logic board work on a 2016?

Tags: mac, logicboard, case

I have an early 2016 MacBook A1534 with a failed SSD.
I was thinking of buying a logic board from the A1534 early 2015. Everything looks fine by the looks of it all connections match up just fine.

But maybe there’s more I don’t know. Can anyone tell me if it will work? Could the pins be different?

<sub>Picture on the left is a 2016 and on the right is a 2015.</sub>

[image: 2016 MacBook Pro Logic Board]
[image: 2015 MacBook Pro Logic Board]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this will not work.

It's not the connectors you have to worry about, it's the screw hole locations and Apple is notorious for changing this very minor but critical detail to prevent this exact thing from happening.

For example, I just finished restoring a Mid-2007 (white) MacBook.  I ordered a bottom case (improperly listed as a 2007) and while every single connector lined up properly, it would not go in because of very subtle differences in where support posts and screw holes were placed - sometimes as little as a couple millimeters.

> Could the pins be different?

Absolutely!  Apple makes changes all of the time depending on the components they source.  The MacBook Pro's you referenced could very well have an issue where the pins are different.  After all, it's the 2016 MacBook Pro models that suffered the "flexgate" (display cable) issue where the 2015's did not.  The cable was made shorter and the back light power pins (21V) were moved too close to a data pin (3V) resulting in machines that had fried GPUs.

My advise is to have the SSD repaired.  There are firms out there that will do board level repair like this for about the same price as you're going to pay for a different logic board.

Comment: Yeah I figured it would cost that much. I even reflowed the board in an oven for a few minutes because I was all out of options and it worked for a good few hours. But unfortunately not a permanent solution.

Comment: That's a whole new can of worms there - reflow.  You should never do that because your oven uses the *average* temp for it's setting.  If you set it to 100° for example, it will go between 75° and 150° where the average temp is 100.  The cheaper the oven the wilder the swing.  Most people cook their chips because of this.

Comment: Oh I see. Yeah I left it on 325F for 7:30 in one of those small toaster ovens. Mind you I had already planned to get rid of this computer it was pretty much already pointless. Surprisingly it worked well for a few hours.

Comment: Depending on the model (the cheap ones use [thermocouples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple)) you could have a temp swing from the high 200s all the way to to the mid to high 300s.   Electronic work requires a *steady* temp (usually high - 370° to 400°) for very short periods of time (5 to 10 seconds). Electronic components aren't designed to spend an hour in an oven.

Comment: Wow never knew it was that inaccurate. I watched a video suggesting I use a laser to measure temp. Either way, I appreciate this useful information. Thank you.

Comment: I only found this out when I really learned to cook.  Pro cooks only use gas because they can fine tune the heat.  They also use copper because it conducts heat most evenly.  I also never knew how much the temp swings were until I bought a Breville oven that kept the temp fine tuned....I never burnt bownies again!

Comment: Hahaha yeah I used to cook for a restaurant and there is a reason cooks ALWAYS use gas ranges, ovens etc. The flame is the best. Besides if you looked inside even my home oven the thermometer on the corner isn’t cleaned from years of use so I’d imagine it’s very inaccurate.